# CDI with Primefaces Charts not rendering properly

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, cdi

I have 4 Primefaces bar charts which sometimes renders, sometimes not. In one of them, I inject a http user session attribute and use it to render the chart (the idea is to show only the data that corresponds to the (logged in) user department).

There are 4 session beans which I'm using the javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped. Sometimes, the Glassfish destroys the instance as expected, but sometimes not.

Based on Exception below, how can I resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

The xhtml below shows the main code for only 2 of the 4 bar charts:

```
<p:tab title="Horas de Treinamento (por Funci)" closable="true" >
 <p:barChart id="horasBars" value="#{chartHorasFunci.modelHoras}" 
    legendPosition="ne" 
    orientation="horizontal"
    seriesColors="AA5555, 00438F"
    xaxisLabel="Horas" yaxisLabel="Funcis"
    title="34 Horas de Treinamento (Orçado/Realizado) por Funci" 
    >
</p:barChart>
</p:tab>

<p:tab title="Horas de Treinamento (por Escritório)" closable="true" titletip="Este subitem impacta no ATB.">
<p:barChart id="horassBarsEsc" value="#{chartHorasEsc.modelHorasEsc}" 
    legendPosition="ne" 
    orientation="vertical"
    seriesColors="AA5555, 00438F"
    xaxisLabel="Prefixo" yaxisLabel="Quantidade"
    title="Horas de Treinamento (Orçado/Realizado) por Prefixo" 
    >
</p:barChart>
```

The session bean below shows the main code for only 1 of the 4 session bean:

```
@Named(value = "chartHorasFunci")
@RequestScoped
public class ChartHorasFunci implements Serializable {

private final BeanLogin sessionPrefDep = new BeanLogin();
private final String sessionAttribute = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("xPrefDep").toString();

public ChartHorasFunci() {
}

@EJB
private CapacitacaoFacade cf;

@EJB
private PrefDepsFacade pf;

private CartesianChartModel modelHoras;

public CartesianChartModel getModelHoras() {
    return modelHoras;
}

public void setModelHoras(CartesianChartModel modelHoras) {
    this.modelHoras = modelHoras;
}

private void HorasChart() {
    List<Capacitacao> orcList = cf.findByPrefDep();
    List<PrefDeps> prefDepsList = pf.findAll();

    sessionPrefDep.setxPrefDep(sessionAttribute);
    System.out.print("from init:" + sessionPrefDep.toString());

    modelHoras = new CartesianChartModel();

    ChartSeries orcHorasSeries = new ChartSeries("Orçado");
    ChartSeries rlzHorasSeries = new ChartSeries("Realizado");

    for (PrefDeps p : prefDepsList) {
        Integer metaHoras = 0;
        Integer rlzHoras = 0;

        Integer x = 0;
        Integer y = 0;

        for (Capacitacao r : p.getCapacitacaoCollection()) {
            if (r.getIdDtRef().getId().intValue() == 1) {
                if (r.getIndicativo().equals("")) {
                    x++;
                }

                if (r.getAtgHoras().equals("Sim")) {
                    y++;
                }
                metaHoras = x.intValue();
                rlzHoras = y.intValue();

            }
        }
    }

    for (Capacitacao o : orcList) {
        if (o.getPrefDep().getPrefDep().toString() == null ? sessionPrefDep.getxPrefDep().toString() == null : o.getPrefDep().getPrefDep().toString().equals(sessionPrefDep.getxPrefDep().toString())) {
            orcHorasSeries.set(o.getFunci(), o.getMetaHoras().getValor());
            rlzHorasSeries.set(o.getFunci(), o.getRlzHoras().floatValue());
        }
    }
    modelHoras.addSeries(orcHorasSeries);
    modelHoras.addSeries(rlzHorasSeries);
}

@PostConstruct
private void initialize() {
    HorasChart();
}

@PreDestroy
public void cleanUp() {
    System.out.println("Destoy the instances here!!"); // <-- sometimes destroys, sometimes not!
}

}
```

The Exception:

```
SEVERE:   Error Rendering View[/capacitacao/capacitacao/index.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /WEB-INF/include/capacitacao/capacitacao/List.xhtml @145,38 value="#{chartHorasFunci.modelHoras}": org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049 Unable to invoke private void br.com.bb.upb.diage.atb.capacitacao.beans.ChartHorasFunci.initialize() on br.com.bb.upb.diage.atb.capacitacao.beans.ChartHorasFunci@3e9c727c
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.bar.BarChartRenderer.encodeData(BarChartRenderer.java:127)
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.bar.BarChartRenderer.encodeScript(BarChartRenderer.java:51)
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.bar.BarChartRenderer.encodeEnd(BarChartRenderer.java:36)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeEnd(TabViewRenderer.java:59)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:559)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabView.visitTree(TabView.java:405)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:399)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:319)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:57)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:417)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf2.impl.listener.phase.CodiLifecycleWrapper.render(CodiLifecycleWrapper.java:126)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049 Unable to invoke private void br.com.bb.upb.diage.atb.capacitacao.beans.ChartHorasFunci.initialize() on br.com.bb.upb.diage.atb.capacitacao.beans.ChartHorasFunci@3e9c727c
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:368)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049 Unable to invoke private void br.com.bb.upb.diage.atb.capacitacao.beans.ChartHorasFunci.initialize() on br.com.bb.upb.diage.atb.capacitacao.beans.ChartHorasFunci@3e9c727c
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:91)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.postConstruct(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:73)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BasicInjectionTarget.java:95)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BeanInjectionTarget.java:65)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:161)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.ForwardingContextual.create(ForwardingContextual.java:27)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:103)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.PassivatingContextWrapper$AbstractPassivatingContextWrapper.get(PassivatingContextWrapper.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:93)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:79)
    at br.com.bb.upb.diage.atb.capacitacao.beans.ChartHorasFunci$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getModelHoras(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:89)
    ... 86 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue full
    at java.util.AbstractQueue.add(AbstractQueue.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.add(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:283)
    at com.sun.common.util.logging.LoggingOutputStream.flush(LoggingOutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:482)
    at com.sun.common.util.logging.LoggingOutputStream$LoggingPrintStream.write(LoggingOutputStream.java:392)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:104)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer(OutputStreamWriter.java:185)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:527)
    at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:669)
    at com.sun.common.util.logging.LoggingOutputStream$LoggingPrintStream.print(LoggingOutputStream.java:297)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.threadio.ThreadPrintStream.print(ThreadPrintStream.java:150)
    at br.com.bb.upb.diage.atb.capacitacao.beans.ChartHorasFunci.HorasChart(ChartHorasFunci.java:80)
    at br.com.bb.upb.diage.atb.capacitacao.beans.ChartHorasFunci.initialize(ChartHorasFunci.java:108)
    ... 91 more

WARNING:   StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDATA tags may not nest
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlResponseWriter.startCDATA(HtmlResponseWriter.java:681)
at javax.faces.context.ResponseWriterWrapper.startCDATA(ResponseWriterWrapper.java:179)
at javax.faces.context.PartialResponseWriter.startError(PartialResponseWriter.java:341)
at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startError(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:156)
at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:200)
at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:124)
at javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerWrapper.handle(ExceptionHandlerWrapper.java:100)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf2.impl.listener.phase.CodiLifecycleWrapper.render(CodiLifecycleWrapper.java:126)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a problem in your application code triggered by `@PostConstruct`. This is the interesting part of the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue full
    at java.util.AbstractQueue.add(AbstractQueue.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.add(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:283)
    at com.sun.common.util.logging.LoggingOutputStream.flush(LoggingOutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:482)
    at com.sun.common.util.logging.LoggingOutputStream$LoggingPrintStream.write(LoggingOutputStream.java:392)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:104)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer(OutputStreamWriter.java:185)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:527)
    at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:669)
    at com.sun.common.util.logging.LoggingOutputStream$LoggingPrintStream.print(LoggingOutputStream.java:297)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.threadio.ThreadPrintStream.print(ThreadPrintStream.java:150)
```

Looks like you're producing more output than the stream can handle, so it's not a CDI problem after all.

Comment: hwellmann, do you know how can I resolve it? Is there any way to configure the stream so it can handle the output produced? Thanks.

Comment: I've set more memory through Glassfish admin console an now it's fine.

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you 'set more memory' in the Glassfish admin console?